# Maven dependency jar with prefix folder

Tags: java, maven

My project pom.xml has a dependency to a 3rd party JAR file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xyz.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>abc</artifactId>    
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I compile my project, maven fails to locate classes in this JAR file. This JAR file is structured as follows:

```
  classes
  |__com
     |__xyz
        |__plugin
           |__<classes>
```

The compilation failed because this 3rd party JAR file has their classes com.xyz.plugin.* located inside the "classes" folder, instead of having the "com" folder at the top most level.  Their MANIFEST file also does not include any classpath specified either.

Is there anyway I can write my pom.xml differently such that compilation will be able to locate the classes correctly within this 3rd party JAR? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where is this third-party jar from? It looks like they have accidentally misconfigured their build (most likely, a conflict between where Maven puts things and assuming that class files are directly under `target`) and should fix that.

Comment: Simply no. This jar is the problem and should be fixed...